# Unity3d Camera rotation not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, rotation

Im trying to make my camera thats stuck to my player turn around it 45 degrees whenever i press Q or E. but for some reason i cant get it to work. im using C#.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class Camera : MonoBehaviour 
{
    int rotatespeed = 3;
    int rotationstart = 90;

    public GameObject player;

    private Vector3 offset;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
    }     

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate() {
            transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("q"))
        {
            Camera.main.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(x + 45 , y, z);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("e"))
        {
            Camera.main.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(x - 45, y, z);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should multiply when rotating

```
    if (Input.GetKey("q"))
    {
        Camera.main.transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(45 , 0, 0);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("e"))
    {
        Camera.main.transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(-45, 0, 0);
    }
```

However this make it look up and down, if you want left and right use the following

```
    if (Input.GetKey("q"))
    {
        Camera.main.transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, 45, 0);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("e"))
    {
        Camera.main.transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, -45, 0);
    }
```

**Important side-note**

Keep in mind that `GetKey` will return true while the user holds it down, which even on a very quick press will result in your camera seemingly spinning out of control due to it still being multiple frames. You most likely want to use `GetKeyDown` which will only return true once every time the user presses the key

Comment: alright, ive changed it a bit, ive also set it to javascript instead of C#. but now the camera is spinning, instead of it spinning around the character. Do you know how to make it spin around an fixed point?